# Couldn't run Visual Studio Android Emulator

Tags: c#, visual-studio, android-emulator, xamarin

When I try to start Android Visual Studio Emulator, I get error "Could not start emulated device 'VS Emulator Lollipop Phone'."

I have installed new Microsoft Android Emulator, restarted my PC, but I'm still unable to run it.

I run: OS: Windows Technical Preview, Visual Studio 15.
Hyper-V enabled both in BIOS and in Features.

Also I try to do this with Xamarin Forms Sample: WorkingWithMaps

What may I did wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to try:

1. Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > User Accounts > Manage
   User Accounts > Advanced > Advanced User Management. Under "Groups,"
   make sure your user account is listed under "Hyper-V
   Administrators." If it is not, you need to add your user account to
   this group.
2. Check which version of Visual Studio 2015 you have
   installed (Preview, CTP 5, or CTP 6) and upgrade if not on the
   latest (latest is available [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/visual-studio-2015-ctp-vs)). Before upgrading, make sure to remove the Visual Studio Emulator for Android from Add/Remove Programs and install via the checkbox in Visual Studio setup.

Let me know if neither of these work. Could you also go to Program Files (x86) > Microsoft XDE > 10.0.0.0, right click XDE.exe, and let me know the File Version listed under the "Details" tab?